# How to Unpivot different columns into rows in dynamic pl sql (oracle sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic, unpivot

how do I use dynamic pl sql to unpivot several different columns into several different rows? With static sql it works well, but with dynamic sql i keep getting errors.
Static sql works fine :

```
SELECT A, B, C, D from table UNPIVOT (
(A,B,C,D) FOR values in (
                        (A_1, B_1, C_1, D_1)as 'cat1',
                        (A_2, B_2, C_2, D_2)as 'cat2',
                        (A_3, B_3, C_3, D_3)as 'cat3',
                        (A_4, B_4, C_4, D_4)as 'cat4'
))p
```

But when i try to translate the same code to dynamic sql it doesn't work, i get errors like missing right
Dynamic sql :

```
Declare 
col_list_A  CLOB;
col_list_B  CLOB;
col_list_C  CLOB;
col_list_D  CLOB;
Viewsql    CLOB;

Begin


SELECT  listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_name)
INTO col_list_A FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'table_xxx' and column_name like 'A_%' ;   

SELECT  listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_name)
INTO col_list_B FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'table_xxx' and column_name like 'B_%' ;    

SELECT  listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_name)
INTO col_list_C FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'table_xxx' and column_name like 'C_%' ;    

SELECT  listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_name)
INTO col_list_D FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'table_xxx' and column_name like 'D_%' ;    

 

Viewsql := 'SELECT A,B,C,D,VAL_NAME FROM table_xxx UNPIVOT (
(A,B,C,D) FOR VAL_NAME IN ('||col_list_A ||','||col_list_B ||','||col_list_C ||','||col_list_D ||')' ; 

execute immediate 'CREATE or REPLACE VIEW table_xxx_view AS ' || viewsql;

End;
/
select * from table_xxx_view
```

When i execute the above dynamic sql i get "missing right parenthesis" error.

But when I modify the dynamic sql query and  unpivot just column A alongside col_list_A, the query is successful. The dynamic query below is successful :

```
Declare 
col_list_A  CLOB;
Viewsql    CLOB;

Begin


SELECT  listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_name)
INTO col_list_A FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'table_xxx' and column_name like 'A_%' ; 

Viewsql := 'SELECT A,VAL_NAME FROM table_xxx UNPIVOT (
A FOR VAL_NAME IN ('||col_list_A ||')' ; 

execute immediate 'CREATE or REPLACE VIEW table_xxx_view AS ' || viewsql;

End;
/
select * from table_xxx_view
```

Thanks in Advance guys

Answer (score 0):

When working with dynamic SQL, it is most often a good idea to **display** statement you're about to execute and then - once you're sure it is OK - actually execute it.

Therefore, if you modify the end of the procedure to

```
<snip>
dbms_output.put_line(viewsql);

--execute immediate 'CREATE or REPLACE VIEW table_xxx_view AS ' || viewsql;
end;
```

you could compare what you prepared with what you expected.

---

For sample table:

```
SQL> create table "table_xxx"
  2  (a_1 number, a_2 number, a_3 number, a_4 number,
  3   b_1 number, b_2 number, b_3 number, b_4 number,
  4   c_1 number, c_2 number, c_3 number, c_4 number,
  5   d_1 number, d_2 number, d_3 number, d_4 number);

Table created.

SQL>
```

this is your static SQL (i.e. that's what you expect) (modified a little bit, though; also, it doesn't return anything but it is correct):

```
SQL> SELECT A, B, C, D from "table_xxx" UNPIVOT (
  2  (A,B,C,D) FOR val_name in (
  3                          (A_1, B_1, C_1, D_1)as 'cat1',
  4                          (A_2, B_2, C_2, D_2)as 'cat2',
  5                          (A_3, B_3, C_3, D_3)as 'cat3',
  6                          (A_4, B_4, C_4, D_4)as 'cat4'
  7  ))p;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

This is, on the other hand, result that your procedure returns:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> Declare
  2      col_list_A  CLOB;
  3      col_list_B  CLOB;
  4      col_list_C  CLOB;
  5      col_list_D  CLOB;
  6      Viewsql    CLOB;
  7  Begin
  8      SELECT  listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_name)
  9      INTO col_list_A FROM all_tab_columns
 10      WHERE table_name = 'table_xxx' and column_name like 'A_%' ;
 11
 12      SELECT  listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_name)
 13      INTO col_list_B FROM all_tab_columns
 14      WHERE table_name = 'table_xxx' and column_name like 'B_%' ;
 15
 16      SELECT  listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_name)
 17      INTO col_list_C FROM all_tab_columns
 18      WHERE table_name = 'table_xxx' and column_name like 'C_%' ;
 19
 20      SELECT  listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_name)
 21      INTO col_list_D FROM all_tab_columns
 22      WHERE table_name = 'table_xxx' and column_name like 'D_%' ;
 23
 24      Viewsql := 'SELECT A,B,C,D,VAL_NAME FROM table_xxx UNPIVOT (
 25      (A,B,C,D) FOR VAL_NAME IN ('||col_list_A ||','||col_list_B ||','||col_list_C ||','||col_list_D ||')' ;
 26
 27      dbms_output.put_Line(viewsql);
 28
 29      --execute immediate 'CREATE or REPLACE VIEW table_xxx_view AS ' || viewsql;
 30  End;
 31  /
```

Result:

```
SELECT A,B,C,D,VAL_NAME FROM table_xxx UNPIVOT (
    (A,B,C,D) FOR VAL_NAME IN
(A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4,C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4,D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

It is obvious that what you get doesn't match what you expect.

Therefore, back to the drawing board and fix the procedure so that it returns correct result.

---

**[EDIT]**

To answer you comment: query you composed just won't work.

For sample table:

```
SQL> desc "table_xxx"
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 A_1                                                NUMBER
 A_2                                                NUMBER
 A_3                                                NUMBER
 A_4                                                NUMBER
 B_1                                                NUMBER
 B_2                                                NUMBER
 B_3                                                NUMBER
 B_4                                                NUMBER
 C_1                                                NUMBER
 C_2                                                NUMBER
 C_3                                                NUMBER
 C_4                                                NUMBER
 D_1                                                NUMBER
 D_2                                                NUMBER
 D_3                                                NUMBER
 D_4                                                NUMBER
```

If you run query that is being returned by your procedure, you get this:

```
SQL> SELECT A,B,C,D,VAL_NAME FROM table_xxx UNPIVOT (
  2      (A,B,C,D) FOR VAL_NAME IN
  3  (A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4,C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4,D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4)
  4  ;
(A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4,C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4,D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4)
 *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
```

while this is what you should've get as a result (as it *executes* without errors):

```
SQL> SELECT A, B, C, D from "table_xxx" UNPIVOT (
  2  (A,B,C,D) FOR val_name in (
  3                          (A_1, B_1, C_1, D_1)as 'cat1',
  4                          (A_2, B_2, C_2, D_2)as 'cat2',
  5                          (A_3, B_3, C_3, D_3)as 'cat3',
  6                          (A_4, B_4, C_4, D_4)as 'cat4'
  7  ))p;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Therefore, no - your procedure doesn't return correct result.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Littlefoot. I inserted  the  dbms_output.put_line(viewsql) part and commented the execute immediate section. It returns same results you have above, the query looks ok, but when i execute immediate, i still get the missing parenthesis error. 

Just to reiterate, my main problem is, I am not able to UNPIVOT (A,B,C,D) simultaneously as seen in my code above.

Comment: No, query doesn't look OK. I added some more info by editing the answer; have a look, please.